# Поле с выпадающим списком select. Изменить цвет текста выделенного option

Tags: html, css, cssselect

Добрый день, друзья!
Имеется поле со списком `select`. Один `option` сделан `disabled` (так как поле со списком не имеет `placeholder`) и `hidden` (чтобы не был виден в списке). Хочу реализовать такую вещь: пока пользователь ничего не выбрал, остается этот как бы "`placeholder`" с серым цветом. Когда выбран `option` - цвет внутри поля черный.
Маялся и так и так, пришлось еще немного помучаться с кастомной стрелочкой.
Друзья, подскажите, как реализовать?

```css
.form_select {
     position: relative;
    }
    
    select {
     margin-bottom: 30px;
     color: #888;
     position: relative;
    }
    
    select:hover {
     cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    /* Targetting Webkit browsers only. FF will show the dropdown arrow with so much padding. */
    @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
     .main_sect_right_side select {
      padding-right: 18px;
     }
    }
    
    
    .form_select::after {
     content:'>';
     font: 21px "Consolas", monospace;
     color:#aaa;
     background-color: #dedede;
     -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
     transform: rotate(90deg);
     right: 5px;
     top: 5px;
     position: absolute;
     pointer-events: none;
     width: 30px;
     height: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="form_select">
     <select>
      <option disabled selected hidden>Choose you hypervisor...</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
     </select>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

По-моему, обесцвечивание у вас уже работает. Только не забудьте поправить цвет option, чтобы они оставались насыщенными:

```
option {
    color: #000;
}
```

К сожалению, вернуть цвет через CSS, похоже, нельзя, но можно сделать как-то так:

```
<select onchange="this.setAttribute('data-selected', true)">
    <option disabled selected hidden>Choose you hypervisor...</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

И в стилях:

```
[data-selected] {
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: круто! спасибо!